# How to track deletion of Files (Content Documents) in Case Feed?

Tags: files, email2case, casefeed

Customer is using Email2Case, configured to store email attachments as Files (Content Document/Version/Link).  They specifically **will** allow agents to delete these files, as they get many unneeded attachments (logo images, etc).  However, they would like to have a record when something is deleted.  Is there any way to configure Case Feed (or History Tracking) to record when a linked File is deleted?

If not with config, could I do it in code?  I could trigger on delete of the ContentDocumentLink to know the file was removed from the case, but what would I create/insert to show the deletion in the feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write trigger on `ContentDocument` in which you need to get reference to `ContentDocumentLink` as it will have the information - with which objects that document has been shared with. Using the links, you can post the feed - using object `FeedItem`.

```
trigger ContentDocTrigger on ContentDocument (before delete) {

    if(Trigger.operationType==System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE) {
        List<ContentDocumentLink> links = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title 
                                           FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                           WHERE ContentDocumentId=:Trigger.oldMap.keySet()];
        System.debug('links => '+links);
        List<FeedItem> feeds = new List<FeedItem>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : links) {
            if(cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType()==Case.SObjectType) {
                feeds.add(new FeedItem(
                    ParentId=cdl.LinkedEntityId,
                    Type='TextPost',
                    Body='File: <b>'+cdl.ContentDocument.Title+'</b> has been deleted',
                    isRichText=true
                ));
            }
        }
        System.debug('feeds => '+feeds);
        if(feeds.size()>0) insert feeds;
    }

}
```