# What populates "Text Posts" in the Lightning Case Chatter Feed?

Tags: sms, casefeed

I noticed a "Text Posts" subtab in the Case Chatter standard component, and wanted to populate it with our SMS tasks.

[image]

Questions:

1. Does anyone know where this Text Posts subtab is pulling its data from?  From the research I've done, it seems like LiveMessage is leveraging this, but couldn't find clear documentation to confirm this
2. Can we populate this subtab with our own Task records marked for SMS (or any other SObject record type)?  How could we accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `FeedItem` object of Type `TextPost`. You can refer to [How to track deletion of Files (Content Documents) in Case Feed?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275942/how-to-track-deletion-of-files-content-documents-in-case-feed/275946#275946) where you will get good idea on how to create the feed programmatically.

For any SObject (even `Task`), you can create feed with its `ParentId`.

Note:

> The following standard objects can have Chatter feeds: Account, Asset,
>   Case, CollaborationGroup, Contact, ContentDocument, Contract,
>   Dashboard, DashboardComponent, Entitlement, Event, KnowledgeArticle,
>   Lead, Opportunity, Product2, Quote, Report, ServiceContract, Site,
>   Solution, Task, Topic, User, WorkOrder, and WorkOrderLineItem.

---

For further understanding, you can refer to [Chatter Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm) and [Chatter Feed Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm).

[image]